# What are the technical and security features of the iPhone 7 fingerprint reader?

Tags: iphone, security, documentation

I'm looking for technical material that describes the quality of the iPhone 7 fingerprint reader, and ideally previous models as well.

My hope, is that the specification is more in alignment with NIST/FBI requirements.

Answer (score 1):

these links may help. The first link is apple's Touch ID privacy info, and the second is about federal government forcing people to unlock their phones using Touch ID.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587

https://9to5mac.com/2016/05/02/federal-court-touch-id-fingerprint/